# I can visit my deleted question, but still it allows to post me the same question with the same content

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, hidden-features

Usually when we add question it suggests relevant existing questions to avoid duplicate question. But it allows if it matches with deleted questions where I can visit the deleted question by url. Shouldnt it be   prevented by the system when the question is submitted?

Answer (score 2):

If you've deleted it, the system won't have it on file as a searchable question.
However, most edits and deletions can be seen by the author and a number of other users. In effect all our posts are tracked.